# Remove all white space between an image tag

Tags: php, html, image, preg-replace, str-replace

i have users submit some text (including random html image links) and then i am trying to create a basic BBCode [img][/img] tag out of the images in the text.

The way i am currently testing is like so:

String (taken from a random forum):

`After a fair few years of doing the usual lowering, fitting wheels etc,when it comes to car modifying, we spent a couple of years doing Minimoto racing all round the country in the Southern British Minimoto Championship winning the 2006 Production Privateer Championship.<br />
<br />
<img src="http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y18/moo0484/scan0001.jpg" border="0" class="tcattdimglink" onload="NcodeImageResizer.createOn(this);" alt="" /><br />
<br />
<img src="http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y18/moo0484/01072007065.jpg" border="0" class="tcattdimglink" onload="NcodeImageResizer.createOn(this);" alt="" /><br />`

I then replace any image properties / change the image tags to bbcode using a function:

```
function convert($text) {
  $text = preg_replace('/class=".*?"/', '', $text);
  $text = preg_replace('/alt=".*?"/', '', $text);
  $text = preg_replace('/src="/', '', $text);
  $text = preg_replace('/border=".*?"/', '', $text);
  $text = preg_replace('/onload=".*?"/', '', $text);
  $text = str_replace("<img", "[img]", "$text");
  $text = str_replace('">', "[/img]", "$text");
  return nl2br($text);
}
```

This works perfectly fine if the tag is not closed with a trailing slash. I could add another rule:

```
  $text = str_replace('"/>', "[/img]", "$text");
```

Which would work, but there is the white space still left from where i removed the properties.

So my question is, can i just remove the white space from between the img tags:

```
  <img />
```

For example, in the preg_replace function the .*? replaces the content between the "".

Can i do a similar thing but with img tags and to remove the white space between them?

I obviously cant just run:

```
  $text = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $text);
```

As i need the white space in the text etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be trying to use regular expressions with `str_replace`. You have to use `preg_replace`.

Comment: just changed it back, was using preg_replace before but decided to change it to str... back to preg now thanks!

Comment: *sidenote* you should run the html through [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), before doing your bbcode conversation, that you should use a proper HTML parser like DOMDocument to extract only what you want, or you **will** open your visitors to all kinds of germs!!

Comment: Downloaded htmlpurifier for now. Any ideas on remove white spaces from between two specified parts of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove any white space and rouge attributes so pretty much all attributes especially the on* Event Attributes like onClick,onBlur. theres are too many ways to add a XSS attack into HTML.Making something that will strip them all out would not be maintainable, so if you want to let users input HTML use [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). Its easily initialized into your code and has lots of options.

A simple alternative would be to just extract the src of the img then remove the attributes and put the src back and make a string of images, then use strip_tags() to remove all HTML and then concatenate your images onto the text. It lacks the positioning of images though.

**So something like:**

```
<?php 
$html = <<<DEMO
After a fair <script>alert('XSS');</script>few ...
winning the 2006 Production Privateer Championship.<br /> 
<div style="background-image: url(javascript:alert('XSS'))"></div>
<br /> 
<img src="http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y18/moo0484/scan0001.jpg" border="0" class="tcattdimglink" onload="NcodeImageResizer.createOn(this);" alt="" /><br /> 
<br /> 
text here
<img src="http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y18/moo0484/01072007065.jpg" border="0" class="tcattdimglink" onload="NcodeImageResizer.createOn(this);" alt="" /><br />
more txt here
DEMO;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

if (false === ($elements = $xpath->query("//*"))) die('Error');

foreach ($elements as $element) {

    //remove script tags
    if($element->nodeName=='script'){
        $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
    }

    //remove empty tags but not images
    if (!$element->hasChildNodes() || $element->nodeValue == '') {
        if($element->nodeName != 'img'){
            $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
        }
    }

    //remove all attributes except links and imgs
    for ($i = $element->attributes->length; --$i >= 0;) {
        $name = $element->attributes->item($i)->name;
        if (('img' === $element->nodeName && 'src' === $name) || ('a' === $element->nodeName && 'href' === $name)){
            continue;
        }
        $element->removeAttribute($name);
    }
}

//put dom together and remove the document body
echo preg_replace('~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|body))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $dom->saveHTML());

/*
<p>After a fair few ...
winning the 2006 Production Privateer Championship.</p>
<img src="http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y18/moo0484/scan0001.jpg"> 
text here
<img src="http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y18/moo0484/01072007065.jpg">
more txt here
*/
```

Though just look into using [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), also the 1990's are calling they want there BBCODE back use markdown instead. ;p

Good luck

Comment: amazing, thanks! bit tired to look through it in depth but it works perfectly in a test environment! Ill have a good read tomorrow and include into current process :)

Comment: I updated answer, first sentence was confusing lol. Good luck

Comment: If you want BBCODE to HTML, [heres one](https://gist.github.com/lcherone/3285cbf0fc8574967f6f)

Comment: I have my reasons for using BBCode :) Im trying to convert users to using my website and 'import' their forum threads. Forum users wont be able to use html markdown but are more than used to the simple BBCode tags. So what i do is allow them to insert BBcode into my website and also convert any html they put in there, into BB code when it is saved into my DB. When the data is displayed, i can easily covert the BBCode to markdown so i can display as i want. When the user wants to edit a post, they see the DB row so its still BBCode. Im using ckeditor which im pretty sure strips out 'bad' code.

Comment: Is there a way to use this method you posted but not add the images to the end of the text? If a string has images mixed in between the text i would like the images to remain where they were. If possible.